# How to set the size of an ElevatedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can't set the size of an Elevated button in Flutter. I have tried enclosing it in a sized box but my code doesn't work. I'm not sure where the size is coming from but I can't change it.

Here's my code:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 60,
      height: 60,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 10,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), // <-- Radius
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          ),
          child: Text(
            table.tableNumber,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

From my scaffold:

```
class TablesShopView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TablesShopView({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => TablesShopViewState();
}

class TablesShopViewState extends State<TablesShopView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showSnackBar(context));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [appBackgroundColorStart, appBackgroundColorEnd],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 12),
                const TablesShop(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class TablesShop extends StatelessWidget {
  const TablesShop({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget<TablesModel>(
      model: TablesModel(api: Provider.of(context, listen: false)),
      onModelReady: (model) => model.fetchTables(),
      child: const SizedBox.shrink(),
      builder: (context, model, child) => model.busy
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : GridView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                // childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                //     (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
              ),
              itemCount: model.tables.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => TableShopListItem(
                table: model.tables[index],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

edit: Because Gridview always maintains its aspect ratio as mentioned in the accepted answer below, the solution for me was to remove the sized box and elevated button dimensions completely and increase the circle radius to 300. With a grid `crossAxisCount` of 5, this maintained a perfect circle at any screen size. While the buttom size will change with the screen size that still works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Wrap` widget for your case. GridItem will maintain aspect ratio for its children.
As for the shape, I think you are trying get  `shape: CircleBorder(),` /`shape: StadiumBorder(),`

```dart
 return Wrap(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
          TableShopListItem(
           ....
          ),
      ],
    );
```

If the top widget is not handling scroll event, wrap the `Wrap` widget scrollable widget.

You can check more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: This made no difference.

Comment: Can you include a full sample widget that will reproduce the issue from scaffold, in flutter constraints go down. sizes go up

Comment: I edited my question to include the requested code.

Comment: Use wrap in your case, or ListView with Row

Comment: I still need a grid. I don't see how to do this with Row.

Comment: well, I am not sure why you've to use gridView with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` and `shrink`. if you are missing  spacing you can get those on Wrap too

Answer (score 1):

you can simply wrap your elevated button within sized box widget and put you desired width and height.

Comment: It already is wrapped in a `SizedBox`. The size doesn't change regardless of the dimensions applied.

Comment: make your elevated button to child of sized box your elevated button is child of padding remove or replace with parent sized box

Answer (score 0):

You can give the button a fixed size:

```
ElevatedButton(
 onPressed: (){},
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
   fixedSize: const Size(150, 50)
  ),
 child: const Text("Press Me")
)
```

Comment: This made no difference. I can enter any numbers I want into the size and nothing changes.